# placement delete function is never called upon exception

Tags: c++, c++11

The placement delete is used to deallocate the memory when an exception occurs in the placement new. So I ran a test:

```
#include <iostream>
#include <new>
using namespace std;
class A {
public:
    A(){
        cout << "constructor" << endl;
        throw 1;
    }
};

void* operator new(size_t size, int i){
    cout << "in placement new" << endl;
    return ::operator new(size);
}

void operator delete(void *ptr, int i){
    cout << "in placement delete" << endl;
    ::operator delete(ptr);
}

int main(){
    int o = 9;
    A* a = new(o) A;
}
```

And the placement delete function was never called, it just simply exited. Why?

Comment: There is no such thing as "placement delete". You defined an `operator delete` function

Comment: @M.M there is no placement `delete` operator syntax, but there are placement `operator delete` functions and this is one of them.

Answer (score 5):

Your program throws an uncaught exception. This means `std::terminate` is called.

In this situation, there may or may not be *stack unwinding* (it is implementation-defined whether or not this happens). Your implementation clearly decides to call `std::terminate` without doing stack unwinding.

The calling of `operator delete` is actually a part of [stack unwinding](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/throw#Stack_unwinding) even though no stack is involved here, it is a bit of a misnomer.

To see your function being called, change the code to:

```
try
{
    A* a = new(o) A;
}
catch(...) {}
```

.

Comment: If a constructor called by `new` throws, then the corresponding `operator delete` function is called, placement or not. It is a part of stack unwinding.

Comment: The constructor and the `new` operator are parts of the call stack. Even though the object being created does not reside on the stack, undoing the effects of `new` is still stack unwinding.

Answer (score 2):

That's because you are not catching the exception so no relevant code for your delete is called. Just wrap it in a `try`/`catch` block:

```
try 
{
    int o = 9;
    A* a = new(o) A;
} 
catch (int i) { }
```

Mind that you must effectively catch the exception raised by your constructor not just any exception.

Answer (score 1):

The placement `operator delete` finction [is being called](https://ideone.com/E9tqS4) if you handle the exception properly.

If you don't handle the exception, the implementation is allowed to terminate your program immediately upon `throw` without unwiding the stack, so, for instance, [no destructors are called](https://ideone.com/aflEyf).

Answer (score 0):

```
class A {
public:
    A(){
        cout << "constructor" << endl;
        throw 1;
    }

    void* operator new(size_t size, int i){
        cout << "in placement new" << endl;
        return ::new A();
    }

    void operator delete(void *ptr){
        cout << "in placement delete" << endl;
        ::operator delete(ptr);
    }
};

int main(){
    int o = 9;
    try
    {
        A* a = new(o) A;
    }
    catch(...)
    {
        cout << "Exception"<< endl;
    }
}
```

It is better to use the overload operator at the class level. Also, you have to use try/catch block.